# How to perform MSMQ Trace

Tags: msmq, trace, etw

I'm looking for a way to trace MSMQ activity (API calls, or something similar)

I saw several references mentioning ETW tracing but they weren't very clear or complete.

Is there a simple tutorial about this subject?

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility to do this. Unfortunately, the output is encrypted and the only way to read it is by sending it to MS.

If you have a MS support contract, I'd call them.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/09/latest-version-1-5-of-the-logging-script-for-msmq-3-0.aspx

That blog has some great MSMQ troubleshooting tips that might also help.

Comment: I saw some references to the file. it appears strange that you need to send it to MS just to read a log file. Is it really readable only by Microsoft?